# c++ combine values from two (or more) parameter packs

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

How is it possible to combine values from two parameter packs in C++?
In other words, how to write function

```
LetsStart<int, -1, 10, 3>("This is -1", "And this is 10", "3!!!");
```

which would output

```
-1 This is -1                                                                                                                                   
10 And this is 10                                                                                                                               
3 3!!!
```

Ie it should pick 1st value from first pack and 1st value from second pack, then 2nd value from both packs, then 3rd value from both packs and so on...

In first my attempts I tried something like this

```
template<class T, T... Firsts, class TSecond>
void LetsStart(TSecond... Seconds) {
   Output((Firsts, Seconds)...);
}
```

but this did not work...

// Of course I [wrote this function](http://pastebin.com/M0mybdEs), but I believe there exists more correct and simple way to accomplish this task. So, could you point me out the way?

Comment: The idea is to store each pack in a tuple (or another class), and then iterate over those two tuples via an index `N` which goes from `0` to `sizeof ... (Firsts)`. I would start answering it, if I wouldn't consider the resulting class a bit useless ... what do you have in mind with this?

Comment: I don't really understand the requirement but why can't you just use a map?

Comment: You're on the right track; you just cannot expand parameter packs in that context. One context where expansion is allowed is a braced-init-list: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c4980989603a770

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, you can use the following function:

```
template<typename T, T... V, typename F, typename... A>
void f(F &&f, A&&... args) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(V) == sizeof...(A), "Argument lists size mismatch");
    int arr[] = { 0, (std::forward<F>(f)(V, std::forward<A>(args)), 0)... };
    (void)arr;
}
```

It accepts two lists of parameters as requested and an extra function `F`, then it unpacks the parameters and pass the *N-th* of each list to the given function.
It should work also in case no parameters are provided.

In C++17 you can rewrite it as it follows:

```
template<typename T, T... V, typename F, typename... A>
void f(F &&f, A&&... args) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(V) == sizeof...(A));
    (std::forward<F>(f)(V, std::forward<A>(args)), ...);
}
```

In both cases I've checked that the two lists have the same size, for it wasn't specified what to do in such a case.

You can test the two functions with the example `main` below:

```
#include<utility>
#include<iostream>

// ...

int main() {
    auto l = [](auto v, auto s) { std::cout << v << " " << s << std::endl; };
    f<int, -1, 10, 3>(l, "This is -1", "And this is 10", "3!!!");
}
```

Comment: Why is forwarding required in call to `f` (`std::forward<F>(f)(/*...*/)`)?

Comment: @InnokentiyAlaytsev to respect reference qualifiers on function call operator, if any.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 version:

CE: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xIUL1J

```
#include<iostream>

template<class... T>
void LetsStart(){}

template<class T, class U>
void print(T t, U u)
{
    std::cout << t << " " << u << '\n';
}

template<class T, T f,  T... ts, class A, class... Arg>
void LetsStart(A&& a, Arg&&... args){
    print(f, a);
    LetsStart<T, ts...>(args...);
}

void foo() {
    LetsStart<int, -1, 10, 3>("This is -1", "And this is 10", "3!!!");
}
```

Comment: The C++11 version, provided by @skypjack, has an important advantage over your implementation - it's not recursive. At the end of the days it doesn't actually matter because the compiler will inline everything. But if one wants to produce debug build, the non-recursive version results in much less assembly and intermediate functions.